# migrating local USB to AirportExtreme USB for Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, backup, airport

I've got Time Machine backing up to a local USB hard drive (i.e. I plug it directly into my Macbook Pro). I now want to use this hard drive as the Time Machine drive hooked up to my AirportExtreme. Will doing so require reformatting the HD? Or will it be a simple plug-and-play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before and all I had to do was connect the HDD to the AirportExtreme and point Time Machine to the new location.

I would recommend copying the backups from the drive to another drive if you can before doing so, there are some instances where Time Machine will reject the backups and then you will need to format the drive.